# Grunt concat multiple JSON files

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I have multiple JSON files, each located in different paths. 
Now I'm trying to concat all files with **"grunt-concat-json"**.

The source JSON files are looking like this:

ExampleA.json

```
[ {
     "configPath": "Example A"
} ]
```

ExampleB.json

```
[ {
   "configPath": "Example B"
} ]
```

How can I configure my GRUNT Task to get following result JSON File:

```
[
   {
       "configPath": "Example A"
   },
   {
       "configPath": "Example B"
   } ]
```

I've tried with this config:

```
concat: {
 json:
     {
        src: [
                'pathA/ExampleA.json',
                'pathB/ExampleB.json
            ],
        dest: 'pathX/Merged.json',
            options: {
                separator: ','
            }
        }
    },
```

With this setting I get following result:

```
[
    {
       "configPath": "Example A"
    }
],
[
   {
       "configPath": "Example B"
   }
]
```

but my result JSON should only have ONE array, which I can loop through in my code like

```
configPaths.forEach(configPath) {  ...  }
```

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to write a custom grunt task for this. Check http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic zero-validation implementation that should be just enough to get you started.

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('concatArrays', 'concatArrays', function() {
    this.files.forEach(function(_set) {
        var combined = [];
        _set.src.forEach(function(_file) {
            combined = combined.concat(JSON.parse(grunt.file.read(_file)));
        });
        grunt.file.write(_set.dest, JSON.stringify(combined));
    });
});
```

You can configure filesets like:

```
concatArrays: {
    local: {
        files: [{
            src: ['a.json', 'b.json'],
            dest: 'combined.json'
        }],
    }
}
```